# SAS xlsx libname engine on Viya 4

Tags: sas, xlsx

I'm trying to access an xlsx file stored on SAS Drive from a SAS Studio session, all on Viya 4.

This piece of SAS documentation suggests that it works on Viya just like in SAS 9.4: https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_031/acpcref/titlepage.htm

However it doesn't go into any details or examples and when I try this code it runs successfully but the resulting library is empty (and in fact changing the path to a non-existing file won't change anything, so I doubt that the file access was working in the first place):

```
libname myxls xlsx "/folders/myfolder/file.xlsx";

proc contents data=myxls._all_;
run;
```

Comment: I think to access "drive" you need to use special filename settings.  I don't think you can combine the options for referencing drive objects with the options for referencing XLSX libref engine.  So you might need two steps.  One to copy to/from "drive" to actual disk file (perhaps in WORK directory) and separate step to read/create the XLSX file on the actual disk.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `filesrvc` access method to access files on SAS Drive.

```
filename myfile filesrvc
    folderpath = '/folders/myfolder/'
    filename   = 'file.xlsx'
;
```

You cannot have direct libname access to files stored on SAS Drive, but you can import them into SAS using `proc import`:

```
proc import 
    file = myfile 
    dbms = 'xlsx' 
    out  = myxls
    replace;
run;
```

If you have persistent storage then you certainly can use standard libname access so long as that file is in that storage location.

If you don't and you'd like to still have libname access, one workaround is to physically copy the xlsx file to your WORK directory, then assign a new libname statement:

```
filename source filesrvc
    folderpath = '/folders/myfolder/'
    filename   = 'file.xlsx'
;

filename dest "%sysfunc(pathname(work))/file.xlsx";

/* Use fcopy to copy from SAS Drive to WORK */
%let rc = %sysfunc(fcopy(source, dest));

libname myxls xlsx "%sysfunc(pathname(work))/file.xlsx";
```

More information on filesrvc:
https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_031/lestmtsglobal/p0qapul7pyz9hmn0zfoefj0c278a.htm

Answer (score 0):

You get empty library if the path isn't correct. Or if your system doesn't understand your path. Remember, you have to have your folders on a server and not on your personal disc.

```
libname myxls  "path\myfolder\file.xlsx";

proc contents data=myxls._all_;
run;
```

This works for me just fine. Maybe your system had issues with using / instead of \ (my setup certainly doesn't work with / ). Or path wasn't correct. Can't be sure unless we get more details about your setup.

Comment: I'm using Viya 4 on Azure. There are no local (as in on my physical machine) components involved. This is just about how to access xlsx files stored on SAS Drive from SAS Studio by using the XLSX engine.